# Sizing Children in a GXT Layout Container

Tags: layout, containers, gxt

I am trying to create a screen layout that has three sections, the top two of which are a fixed size, and the last of which should expand to fill the remaining space on the screen. I'm using a VerticalLayoutContainer (VLC), which contains three HorizontalLayoutContainers (HLCs). I've attempted to control the size of the HLCs using VerticalLayoutData definitions. I don't want to specify a fixed height for the HLCs because I don't know what they will contain until runtime. The problem that I'm having is that the HLCs are all being placed at position 0,0 in the VLC, and are thus overlaying one another. Here's what this looks like (it's a mess!):

[image: HLCs in a VLC]

Here's the UiBinder code that I'm using:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM 'http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent'>
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:gwt='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
  xmlns:gxtbutton='urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button'
  xmlns:gxtcontainer='urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container'
  xmlns:gxtform='urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form'
  xmlns:gxt='urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client'
  xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
  <!-- VerticalLayoutData declarations ========================================================= -->
  <ui:with
    type='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData'
    field='fillRemainingLayoutData'>
    <ui:attributes height='1' width='1'/>
  </ui:with>
  <ui:with
    type='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData'
    field='sizeToContentsLayoutData'>
    <ui:attributes height='-1' width='1'/>
  </ui:with>
  <!-- ========================================================================================= -->
  <gxtcontainer:Viewport>
    <gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
      <gxtcontainer:child layoutData='{sizeToContentsLayoutData}'>
        <gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
          <gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
            <gxtform:FieldLabel text='Person.FirstName'/>
          </gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
          <gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
            <gxtform:FieldLabel text='Person.EmailAddress'/>
          </gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
        </gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
      </gxtcontainer:child>
      <gxtcontainer:child layoutData='{sizeToContentsLayoutData}'>
        <gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
          <gxtbutton:TextButton text='Save Changes'/>
          <gxtbutton:TextButton text='Undo Changes'/>
        </gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
      </gxtcontainer:child>
      <gxtcontainer:child layoutData='{fillRemainingLayoutData}'>
        <gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
          <gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
            <gxtbutton:TextButton text='Organizations'/>
            <gxtbutton:TextButton text='Relationships'/>
          </gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
          <gxtcontainer:CardLayoutContainer>
            <gxt:ContentPanel headerVisible='false'/>
            <gxt:ContentPanel headerVisible='false'/>
          </gxtcontainer:CardLayoutContainer>
        </gxtcontainer:HorizontalLayoutContainer>
      </gxtcontainer:child>
    </gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
  </gxtcontainer:Viewport>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And just for completeness, here's the UiBinder Java class:

```java
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class PersonDetailsWidget extends Composite {
//==================================================================================================
interface PersonDetailsWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, PersonDetailsWidget> { //
}
//==================================================================================================
public PersonDetailsWidget() {
  final PersonDetailsWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(PersonDetailsWidgetUiBinder.class);
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

And here's the entry point class:

```java
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;

public class GXTGrid implements EntryPoint {
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
  final PersonDetailsWidget personDetailsWidget = new PersonDetailsWidget();
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(personDetailsWidget);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

I'm very open to any suggestions for alternative/"correct" approaches to this!

** Edit **

After replacing the `VerticalLayoutContainer` widgets with `VBoxLayoutContainer` widgets, and the `HorizontalLayoutContainer` widgets with `HBoxLayoutContainer` widgets, and removing the layout data entries, the overlap problem is resolved. But now the labels and buttons are truncated. Here's the result:

[image]

Note: if I execute a `ResizeContainer#forceLayout` on the outermost `VBoxLayoutContainer` then the buttons are all visible; but the field labels are still truncated.

Comment: Why don't you use `HorizontalLayoutData`? I think you are supposed to use it and specify for each widget in your `HorizontalLayoutContainer` a relative size with double. Like this for example: `hlc.add(widget1,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.5,1);` `hlc.add(widget2,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.5));`. This way widget 1 and widget 2 will be using one half of the available space of hlc each. (Sorry this is classic java code and not UiBinder but I am sure you can figure out how to change it to UiBinder)

Comment: @RadASM I want the HLCs to be sized to fit their contents, for example, if I have two `FieldLabel` widgets in the HLC then I want the HLC to be the height of two `FieldLabel`s. It's quite possible that I'm using the wrong container, but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Comment: Actually I guess I was right you definitely use the right containers buit in order to make it work and display properly you should specify how your `HorizontalLayoutContainer` must be "split", and right now the only way I know to do so is through `HorizontalLayoutData`. Sorry I can not help you more with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HorizontalLayoutContainer within a VerticalLayoutContainer **has** to have a height set. It's just how it works.
You should use a HBoxLayoutContainer instead. Here a quick example (without the use of UIBinder):

```
    VerticalLayoutContainer vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

    HBoxLayoutContainer hbc1 = new HBoxLayoutContainer();
    hbc1.add(new Label("Person.FirstName:"));
    hbc1.add(new Label("Person.EmailAddress:"));
    vlc.add(hbc1, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));

    HBoxLayoutContainer hbc2 = new HBoxLayoutContainer();
    hbc2.add(new TextButton("Save Changes"));
    hbc2.add(new TextButton("Undo Changes"));
    vlc.add(hbc2, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
```

And that's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Darek ... I'll try this, and flag this as the accepted answer if it works. Do you recommend using the "box" containers everywhere, instead of the non-box containers?

Comment: I replaced the `VerticalLayoutContainer` widgets with `VBoxLayoutContainer` widgets, and the `HorizontalLayoutContainer` widgets with `HBoxLayoutContainer` widgets, and removed the layout data entries. This does indeed remove the overlap problem. But now the labels and buttons are truncated. I've added a picture of this to the main question.

Comment: *Personally*, I don't use BoxLayoutContainers very often. I mostly don't encounter your use case. As you see in my example, I only use a HBoxLayoutContainer but keep the VerticalLayoutContainer (don't use VBoxLayoutContainer). I've updated my code and image to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: The size to contents (using the `VerticalLayoutData`) did the trick, combined with using `VerticalLayoutContainer` to contain the `HBoxLayoutContainer`.